# Select font (face) for AucTeX section styles

Tags: emacs, fonts, auctex

Is there a way to select the font (face) and size for the AucTeX section styles? 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Faces.html?

```
M-x customize-group RET font-latex-highlighting-faces RET
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a general way to change any font you see in Emacs.  Move point to the text in question and hit `C-u C-x =`.  You will get a `*Help*` buffer with something like:

```
There are text properties here:
  face                 font-lock-variable-name-face
```

The face name is a link that you can open.  This gives you a description of the face, with the first line being:

```
Face: font-lock-variable-name-face (sample) (customize this face)
```

`customize this face` is a link that takes you to the appropriate Customize buffer.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that keybinding doesn't work for me.